# What are the main policy differences between Emmerson Mnangagwa and Grace Mugabe?

Tags: coup, zimbabwe

Most of the reporting around recent events in Zimbabwe merely notes the high notes (military deposed Mugabe, seemingly mostly to prevent his wife Grace from succeeding him as a ruler, presumably in favor of Emmerson Mnangagwa).

However, none of the pieces seemed to go into nuts and bolts of **why** the army prefered Emmerson Mnangagwa over Grace Mugabe? Presumably, she would continue Mugabe's policies and the army was content enough with them to not express any displeasure till Mnangagwa was fired from Vice Presidency last week. Are there meaningful predicted policy differences between Emmerson Mnangagwa and Grace Mugabe?

Answer (score 12):

The [BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-41995876) shows Mnangagwa to be a politically shrewd and occasionally ruthless autocrat who was in tight with the military. On a more positive note, he did also try to get some commercial activities going in this economically destitute country.

[Grace Mugabe](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-30307333) has been slowly accumulating power and ousting potential adversaries over the last several years. Her time in power appears to be largely self servant, focusing on accumulating more for her personally rather than building support by improving the lives of people.

It appears that she outreached herself by engineering the expulsion of Mnangagwa, and the military chose to back him instead. And, it was about time for Robert Mugabe to go... it's not like his 37 years in power have been good for the country.

But, inasfar as policy goes, neither appears to exhibit the characteristics that might suggest they could improve the condition of the country. This looks more like a struggle between two power grabbers in an unrepresentative and corrupt government.